# What do I do when my query string in an elasticsearch is too long and the search doesn't work?

Tags: elasticsearch, graphql

I'm querying Elastic in my GraphQL resolver like this below. The peopleArray under the second multi_match is dynamic and is filled with numbers (e.g. [101, 102, 103...]). This is for different users to get their messages. If the user's peopleArray has 165 items, it works fine. However, I have test users who have 1873 items in the peopleArray and the query doesn't work. And I may need to support users with 60,000 items. Basically, I'm creating a messaging system for employees in a company and all the numbers are all the people in their network of message-sending. If this is not a practical way of doing this, any suggestions would be appreciated. But if it is possible, how do I get my results? (Have not tried this in the Kibana UI yet.)

````
const esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
   host: config.elasticsearchRoot
});
const result = await esClient.search({
       index: `${config.index.messageStream}`,
       body: {
         query: {
           bool: {
             must: [
                     {
                       multi_match: {
                         query: tenantId,
                         fields: [
                           "tenantId",
                           "discretionary.clientKey.systemTenantId",
                           "clientKey.systemTenantId",
                           "author.tenantId"
                         ],
                         operator: "OR"
                       }
                     },
                     {
                       multi_match: {
                         query: peopleArray,
                         fields: ["author.peopleId", "details.recipient.peopleId"],
                         operator: "OR"
                       }
                     }
               ]
           }
         },
         from,
         size,
         docvalue_fields: [
           {
             field: "sortDate",
             format: "use_field_mapping"
           }
         ],
         sort: {
           sortDate: {
             missing: "_last",
             unmapped_type: "long",
             order: "desc"
           }
         }
       }
     });```
````

Comment: Consider storing the `peopleArray` in ElasticSearch. In short, the data as stored in ElasticSearch should be tuned for searching/querying. ES is not a database, relational or otherwise. Keep your single source of truth in your database and only use ES as a search engine.

Comment: what kind of datatype are the field to query against peopleArray ? text or keyword, or both?

Comment: The problem is that peopleArray is different based upon the user. I get all the members of peopleArray from a REST call that I make before the search above. So I would have to hardcode different peopleArrays based upon different users in order to put it in ES. I'm not sure if it's text or keyword because I didn't write the data to ES, but I will find out.